# What is the End of Train Device RF Path?

Tags: rf, antenna, radio

A railway end of train (EOT) device is applied to the last car in a train consist.  It communicates in the 450 MHz band with a head of train device in the lead locomotive.  Modern trains can reach upwards of 14,000 feet - almost 3 miles long.  The EOT is mounted on the knuckle of the last car (about 3 feet off of the ground) essentially behind a wall of steel. It has an integrated Omni antenna with 8W RF power.  How does the RF travel to and from the head of the train to the end of the train?

Comment: 8Watts and three miles over (flattish) ground?  No problem.   Imagine a huge search light back there, pointed at the ground.  Plenty of it will reflect and bounce around (and even go around the corners of the caboose) to be "seen" by the receiver on the engine.

Comment: 3 miles is a long train by any standard. The world record is only about 4 miles and this had mid-train locomotives as traction  helpers. That would imply a distance of only 2 miles but it never probably used radio so, where are you getting 3 miles from (2.65 miles = 14,000 feet).

Comment: Also, tracks almost always have a bit of a curve.  Over a couple of miles that'd be enough for the caboose to see the engine.

Comment: Could the train carriages themselves be acting as a waveguide?  Would 66cm wavelength RF energy propagate lengthwise down the metal "tube" shape of the carriages?  I guess the contents of the carriages would largely affect this also.  Or perhaps the RF would simply reflect off the metallic end of the first carriage it strikes?

Comment: Appreciate the replies.  To the first reply:  in some cases the terrain is challenging - with the railroad tracks in rock cuts in the Canadian shield, hills, elevations, curves and heavily wooded areas.  Not only is there not line of sight, there is a huge obstruction between head of train and end of train.

Comment: Second comment: should have said "approaching 3 miles" - apologies.  Trains are getting longer, not shorter.  Lots of activity to lengthen sidings to 20,000 feet in some cases.

Comment: Third reply:  That's what I'm thinking - the cars themselves may be acting as some sort of wave guide.  I'm not an engineer but otherwise how does the RF get to the head of the train apart from reflections?  I'm wondering if there are any studies on that.

Answer (score -1):

Let's use [one of the many online link budget calculators](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-link-budget.aspx) to get a rough idea of received power of the free-space path over 3 miles:

[image: RF Link Budget]

We have just under -60dBm at the receive end. That's still a fairly strong signal - people with good hearing [can discern -60dBm on a good crystal radio.](http://theradioboard.com/rb/viewtopic.php?t=6396)

This is partially due to the relatively high 8W transmit power level - some end of train devices use **compressed air from the train's brakes** to generate electrical power for the radios.

But your instinct is correct - in spite of the "easy" link budget, end-of-train devices **do encounter dead spots along a route** where the link does *not* work - it's part of the statistical nature of mobile communications.

Back to your question, railway operators typically use a [repeater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeater) at known bad spots (e.g. [tunnels](https://earthstonestation.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/036.jpg)) when it's important to keep the link working.

Comment: While the idea of the link budget calculator is interesting, my understanding is that it is based on line of sight transmission or else  along a transmission line with known RF loss characteristics.  In this case, we don't really know the path the RF is taking from the rear to the front of the train.  Particularly unique in this situation is the large "wall" of steel immediately behind the end of train device.  Beside doing meticulous RF measurements along the whole train, I wish there were a better way of visualizing how the RF is getting there.

Comment: @DavidH indeed, the free-space path calculation simply  shows that the signal is 40dB or 10000 (or more) times stronger that what is needed. But it gets easier to accept that the link wil work if only 0.01% of the signal "sneaks around" to the other side :)

Comment: true, but the question remains how does the 0.01% get there?  Is it purely reflection or are the cars or the rails somehow acting as a transmission line for 452/457 MHz?